# Extension of a $\sigma$-additive premeasure on a $\pi$ system to a measure on its $\sigma$ algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem):

> Let $R$ be a ring of subsets of a set
> $Ω$ and $μ: R → [0, + ∞]$ be a $\sigma$-additive pre-measure on a $R$.

> The Carathéodory's extension theorem states that there exists a measure $μ′: σ(R) → [0, + ∞]$ such that $μ′$ is an extension of $μ$.

I was wondering if an extension exists when $R$ is a $\pi$ system?

The reason for considering a $\pi$ system is [because](https://planetmath.org/UniquenessOfMeasuresExtendedFromAPiSystem) a measure on a sigma algebra generated by a $\pi$ system is uniquely determined by its restriction on the $\pi$ system, if the measure is $\sigma$-finite wrt the $\pi$ system. I want to know about the existence of extension instead.

Thanks an regards!

Comment: The section "Extensions of Set Functions to Lattices" of the book
"H. König, Measure and Integration: An Advanced Course in Basic Procedures and Applications, Springer, 1997, corr. reprint 2009, pp. XXI+260." is relevant. It gives necessary and sufficient criteria for extending set functions on pi-systems to larger systems of sets.

Comment: It is worth point out, also, that if there underlying space $\Omega$ is finite, then you can indeed extend from a $\pi$-system. See [these notes, section 2.2 (pdf)](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall17/sta711/lec/wk-02.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\Omega = (0,1)$ and let $R = \{(0,t) : 0 < t < 1\}$ be the collection of all open intervals whose left endpoint is $0$. Then $R$ is certainly a $\pi$-system and $\sigma(R)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  Define $\mu : R \to [0, +\infty]$ by $\mu(A) = 1$ for all $A \in R$.  This is trivially $\sigma$-additive because $R$ contains no disjoint sets!  But $\mu$ cannot extend to a $\sigma$-additive measure $\mu'$ on $\sigma(R)$.  (If $\mu'((0,t)) = 1$ for all $t$ then by continuity from above $\mu(\emptyset) = 1$ which is absurd.)

Comment: Thanks! Is $\mu$ also $\sigma$-finite wrt $R$, because there exists $A_n := (0, \frac{n-1}{n}), n \in\mathbb{N}$ that satisfy $\cup_n A_n = \Omega$ and $\mu(A_n)=1< \infty$?